# MySQL select only categories who have childs or sub-categories

Tags: mysql

I want to get only categories that have sub-categories or prodcuts inside this category. So empty categories should not be displayed.

Here is my last try:

```
SELECT *
        FROM categories as c
        WHERE c.parent = '3' # dynamic $id
        AND c.visible = 'yes'
        AND (
                (
                    SELECT count(*)
                    FROM products
                    WHERE products.categorie = c.id
                ) > 0
                OR
                (
                    SELECT count(*)
                    FROM categories as b
                    #WHERE b.parent = c.id
                ) > 0
            )
        ORDER BY position DESC, `name` ASC
```

`categories.id` is the primary key from the categories table.
`categories.parent` contains the `id (primary key)` from the parent categorie.
`products.categorie` contains the `id (primary key)` from the categories which is its parent.
`categories.visible` is a manually set property and can be ignored.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
SELECT categories.*
FROM categories
WHERE categories.parent = '1'
AND categories.visible = 'yes'
AND (
        (SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE products.categorie  = categories.id AND visible = 'yes') > 0
        OR
        (SELECT count(*) FROM categories as sub WHERE sub.parent = categories.id) > 0
    )
ORDER BY `position` DESC, `name` ASC;
```